# Web users don't see ios users in agora sdk

Tags: ios, capacitor, agora.io

I have implemented agora sdk into web, using capacitorjs framework. It works fine on all devices browsers, like ios safari, android chrome, desktops etc. It also works fine on android WebView. There appeard problem on ios. In docs is written that there must be a native implementation for ios. I used sample from official agora documentation (https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Audio-Call/tree/master/Group-Voice-Call/OpenVoiceCall-iOS) and it looks that ios users hear everyone else, but nobody hear ios users. What did i wrong? Is there any additional magic setting? I tested on ios 13. Here is ios implementation:

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor
import AgoraRtcKit

@objc(AgoraIos)
public class AgoraIos: CAPPlugin {

    var agoraKit: AgoraRtcEngineKit!

    @objc func initialize(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
      let appId = call.getString("appId");
      agoraKit = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: appId, delegate: nil);
      call.resolve();
    }

    @objc func join(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        let channelName = call.getString("channelName");
        let userId = call.getString("userId");
        agoraKit.joinChannel(byToken: nil, channelId: channelName, info:nil, uid: userId) {[unowned self] (sid, uid, elapsed) -> Void in
            self.agoraKit.setEnableSpeakerphone(true);
            call.resolve();
        }
    }

    @objc func leave(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        agoraKit.leaveChannel(nil);
        call.resolve();
    }

    @objc func talk(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        agoraKit.muteLocalAudioStream(true);
        call.resolve();
    }

    @objc func mute(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        agoraKit.muteLocalAudioStream(false);
        call.resolve();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably passing a different channel name. Have you verified that the channels are identical at runtime? This code doesn't show those values. It's also possible you have a different appId.

Comment: ios user can hear web users. It implies that they are in same room. Isn't it?

Comment: You're right. But I see your problem. You're passing the wrong values to `muteLocalAudioStream`, assuming you're calling `talk()` at some point.

Comment: I had many tries with different configurations. In official example (I linked above) it's the same story. Also users on the web doesn't see any event that there is a new person in the channel.

Comment: What version of the Agora SDK are you using? If you're below 3.0.0, you need to call enableWebSdkInteroperability to make the iOS SDK work with the web SDK. (3.0.0 onward has it enabled by default).

Comment: @ZontanFerrah good point. I will try to implement it as it is written here. https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/interop_faq

Comment: Hello, I am in a strange issue. With ios agora it works on the agora sample tester weblink provided by agora docs, but doesn't connects with neither of web and android, with same appId, channel name. Any body faced this issue?